# Troubles setting up Hidden Service

Tags: configuration, onion-services

I've done some looking for my problem and I've learned a bit but still get the same result. The "result" is when I uncomment my hidden service lines in my torrc, tor will not start and not produce any logs. When I comment them all is good.

Initially I was using just the browser, trying to start a hidden service there. I read an article from someone having similar experiences and went to `#tor` channel on irc. They went to https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en and installed the tor package. I did too. I chose option 2.

I already downloaded apache2, php5 and mysql. I followed instructions to make each more secure. I have a test web page. In my tor browser after disabling the proxy for 127.0.0.1 I can view my webpage.

Once I had it installed I then proceeded to https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en . Where I have already been trying to configure my browser. I was on IRC earlier tonight but no one could help. We went over things more thoroughly... the only thing I can think of is permissions but am not sure.

**Versions**

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Tor v0.2.7.6
Libevent 2.0.21
OpenSSL 1.0.1f
Zlib 1.2.8
```

**File Ownership**

`/var/lib/tor/hidden_service (drwx--S---)` - `debian-tor:debian-tor`

`/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/srv (drwxr-s---)` - `debian-tor:debian-tor`

`/etc/tor/torrc (-rw-r--r--)` - `root:root`

I'm unsure what the difference between the upper- and lowercase S is. Or why `srv` has group read. (Might've been something I did just don't remember.)

I'm not a member of the `debian-tor` group.

**Starting/Stopping**

`sudo service tor [start|stop|restart]`

**Config files**

Without my attempt to run a hidden service they are unchanged. To run a hidden service I uncommented the lines in the `/etc/tor/torrc` file and changed them to read:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/srv
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

That was my only change.

**Output**

Restarting the daemon with the original torrc file I get two lines:

```
 * Stopping tor daemon...                   [OK]
 * Starting tor daemon...                   [OK]
```

Uncommenting the hidden service lines and restarting I get:

```
 * Checking if your tor configuration is valid
<date> [notice] Tor v0.2.7.6 running on Linux with Libevent 2.0... blah blah
<date> [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong... blah blah
<date> [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
<date> [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
<date> [warn] Permissions on directory/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/srv are too permissive.
<date> [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
<date> [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

The thing is if I remove my log file and restart with hidden services enabled... I get no log. However as soon as I recomment the lines and restart I now have a log file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [unsetting the `setgid`](https://superuser.com/a/509127/320232) bit on your directories.

You're [aiming for permissions](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/9133/1730) of either `600` or `700`. The `setgid` bit is presumably a security concern as it indicates other users might have execute permissions on someone else's files.

Comment: I wish Tor was a little more specific on indicating that on Step #2 (https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en). That fit the bill. Worked instantly. Tested it with the .onion address, all good. TYVM. (I emailed a suggestion for change on that page.)